# Question about Duhamel's principle.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I know how to apply Duhamel's principle to solve a problem, but I don't quite understand a fine detail regarding it.

$ \begin{cases}
u_t = ku_{xx} + f(x,t) , & x \in \mathbb{R}, t > 0\\
u(x,0) = 0, & x \in \mathbb{R}
\end{cases}$

In order to solve this with Duhamel's principle we consider,

$ \begin{cases}
w_t(x,t,\tau) = kw_{xx}(x,t,\tau) , & x \in \mathbb{R}, t > 0\\
w(x,0,\tau) = f(x,\tau), & x \in \mathbb{R}
\end{cases}$

and solve this homogenous PDE, and the solution is given by

$$w(x,t,\tau) = \int_{\mathbb{R}}\Phi(x-y,t)f(y,\tau)~dy. $$

How do we know that adding the variable  $\tau$ does not effect the validity of the standard solution of the heat equation? How do we know the proof still works out for the heat equation? By proof, I mean the proof that the bottom statement is true.

I know that the solution works if this were the case,

$ \begin{cases}
w_t(x,t) = kw_{xx}(x,t) , & x \in \mathbb{R}, t > 0\\
w(x,0) = f(x), & x \in \mathbb{R}
\end{cases}$

and it would be given by,
$$w(x,t) = \int_{\mathbb{R}}\Phi(x-y,t)f(y)~dy. $$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that $\tau$ is just a parameter in the equation, which only involves derivatives with respect to $t$ and $x$. If you fix $\tau$, you are in the standard situation. A similar situation is: the general solution of the PDE for $u(x,y)$
$$
u_x=0
$$
is just the solution of the ODE $y'=0$, $y=C$, the only difference being that since $y$ plays the role of a parameter, it would be $u(x,y)=C(y)$.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense, the concept  just does not seem very intuitive to me.

Comment: @Johndoe It might be helpful to use different notation, something like $w^{(\tau)}(x,t)$, each of which satisfies the heat equation with only a different initial condition.