# Can $f(x,y)$ be logically equivalent to $f(x)$?

Tags: functions, partial-differential-equations, proof-explanation

Let us say a Theorem is true for $f(x)$ where $f$ is a smooth function from the real numbers to the real numbers. Let us now say that $f(x,y)$ is a smooth function from $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ to the real numbers. Let us fix $y$, can we use $f(x,y)$ in the place of $f(x)$ in a proof? I see this done often in proofs regarding partial differential equations, but I don't really understand what it means to fix a variable ( I have a slight intuitive understanding) nor do I understand how these two can be logically equivalent in a proof situation, how do we know that adding an extra variable won't cause the proof to "blow up"? It is really annoying, since it is done a lot in textbooks.

I can understand for example if a property holds for a group, then it will hold for the additive subgroup of the ring but not the ring itself because the additive subgroup of the ring is indeed a group, and hence we can 'feed' it in the proof of the theorem about groups.

This relates back to my first question,

[Question about Duhamel's principle.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3878804/question-about-duhamels-principle).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, let say you have a function $f : \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$.  If you want to rigorously prove that you can use your theorem, you should proceed as follow.

Let $y\in\mathbb R$. Then we can define $g : \mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ by
$$
g(x) = f(x,y)
$$
You can now apply your theorem on the function  $g$. This implies for example that for any $x\in\mathbb R$, $g(x)$ verifies some property, and so $f(x,y)$ too.

Since $y$ was arbitrary, you deduce that this is true for any $y$. Therefore, for any $(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2$, $f(x,y)$ verifies the property.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x,y)=x+y$. If you want to prove some property of the function $x+3$, you can fix $y$ and prove for $f(x,3)$. That's what it means.